# Close bootsrap card (forever)

Tags: php

so right now I´m editting this social network template, and there´s a boostrap card that shows up on your profile when you haven´t completed it yet, so it gives you a percentage depending on the fields you have already filled out. After completing +80% of the fields the card goes away.

I created an "X" close button so people can close this card without beeing forced to fill all the information. The problem of course is that after refreshing the page it will appear again.

I was thinking that I could maybe make that button change the state of your profile_completion to 100 automatically but I have no idea on how to do it. Thanks.

```
<!-- panel [profile completion] -->
                    {if isset($profile['profile_completion']) && $profile['profile_completion'] < 80}
                        <div class="card" id="profilecompletion">
                            <div class="card-header bg-transparent">

                            <button data-dismiss="alert" data-target="#profilecompletion" type="button" class="close" arial-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button>
                            

                                
                                <span class="float-right">{$profile['profile_completion']}%</span>
                                <strong>{__("Profile Completion")}</strong>
                                <div class="progress mt5">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{$profile['profile_completion']}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {$profile['profile_completion']}%"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="mb5">
                                    {if $profile['user_picture_default']}
                                        <span class="text-link js_profile-image-trigger">
                                            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle mr5"></i>{__("Add your profile picture")}
                                        </a>
                                    {else}
                                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle green mr5"></i>
                                        <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">{__("Add your profile picture")}</span>
                                    {/if}
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb5">
                                    {if $profile['user_cover_default']}
                                        <span class="text-link js_profile-cover-trigger">
                                            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle mr5"></i>{__("Add your profile cover")}
                                        </a>
                                    {else}
                                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle green mr5"></i>
                                        <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">{__("Add your profile cover")}</span>
                                    {/if}
                                </div>
                                {if $system['biography_info_enabled']}
                                    <div class="mb5">
                                        {if !$profile['user_biography']}
                                            <a href="{$system['system_url']}/settings/profile">
                                                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle mr5"></i>{__("Add your biography")}
                                            </a>
                                        {else}
                                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle green mr5"></i>
                                            <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">{__("Add your biography")}</span>
                                        {/if}
                                    </div>
                                {/if}
                                <div class="mb5">
                                    {if !$profile['user_birthdate']}
                                        <a href="{$system['system_url']}/settings/profile">
                                            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle mr5"></i>{__("Add your birthdate")}
                                        </a>
                                    {else}
                                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle green mr5"></i>
                                        <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">{__("Add your birthdate")}</span>
                                    {/if}
                                </div>
                                {if $system['relationship_info_enabled']}
                                    <div class="mb5">
                                        {if !$profile['user_relationship']}
                                            <a href="{$system['system_url']}/settings/profile">
                                                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle mr5"></i>{__("Add your favorite game")}
                                            </a>
                                        {else}
                                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle green mr5"></i>
                                            <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">{__("Add your favorite game")}</span>
                                        {/if}
                                    </div>
                                {/if}
                                {if $system['work_info_enabled']}
                                    <div class="mb5">
                                        {if !$profile['user_work_title'] || !$profile['user_work_place']}
                                            <a href="{$system['system_url']}/settings/profile/work">
                                                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle mr5"></i>{__("Add your work info")}
                                            </a>
                                        {else}
                                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle green mr5"></i>
                                            <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">{__("Add your work info")}</span>
                                        {/if}
                                    </div>
                                {/if}
                                {if $system['education_info_enabled']}
                                    <div class="mb5">
                                        {if !$profile['user_edu_major'] || !$profile['user_edu_school']}
                                            <a href="{$system['system_url']}/settings/profile/earnings">
                                                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle mr5"></i>{__("Add your earnings")}
                                            </a>
                                        {else}
                                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle green mr5"></i>
                                            <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">{__("Add your earnings")}</span>
                                        {/if}
                                    </div>
                                {/if}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                    <!-- panel [profile completion] -->
```

Just the close button itself:

```
<button data-dismiss="alert" data-target="#profilecompletion" type="button" class="close" arial-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button>
```

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. This question has nothing to do with .NET's Task Parallel Library

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable card after first time user closes it. Then you need to make a Ajax request to set the `$profile['profile_completion']` to 100 when the close button clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you attach any guide or docs recommended to do this? I´m kinda new with it, regards